# From multidimensional array i want to extract single column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Input :

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [has_point] => 0
        [xpr] => 0
        [war] => 0
        [sty] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 52
        [has_point] => 0
        [xpr] => 0
        [war] => 0
        [sty] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 34
        [has_point] => 1
        [xpr] => 300
        [war] => 0
        [sty] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 47
        [has_point] => 0
        [xpr] => 0
        [war] => 0
        [sty] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 57
        [has_point] => 1
        [xpr] => 500
        [war] => 0
        [sty] => 0
    )
```

)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 52
    [3] => 34
    [4] => 47
    [5] => 57
)
```

So is there any function in PHP to obtain this output so i don't have to write my own.

I tried

```
function customArraySearch($array, $search) {
    $col = array();
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        $col[] = $v[$search];
    }
    return $col;
}
```

I am getting my output but I want to optimize my code so if there are 10000 records in array it take some time. Please suggest any inbuilt php function

Answer (score 6):

The function you need is *[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)*.

```
$id_array = array_column($your_array, 'id');
```

**Note:** Supported version is **PHP 5 >= 5.5.0**

Comment: Have you got this work? If yes kindly accept the answer so it helps future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 $aa = array(
    array(11, 0,0,0,0),
    array(52, 0,0,0,0),
    array(34, 0,0,0,0),
    array(47, 0,0,0,0),
    array(57, 0,0,0,0)

    );

     $newarray=array();
    foreach( $aa as $k => list($a, $b,$c,$d,$e)) {
    $newarray[]=$a;
    }
    print_r($newarray);
```

Supported version is **(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)**